# JSF on Google App Engine - java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FaceletCache

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsf-2, mojarra

Using GAE 1.5.5 and Mojarra 2.0.6 FCS, I see the message below in the startup log.

It also occurs with Mojarra 2.0.4 which is the version given in the article [Configuring JavaServer Faces 2.0 to run on the Google App Engine Using Eclipse](https://sites.google.com/a/wildstartech.com/adventures-in-java/Java-Platform-Enterprise-Edition/JavaServer-Faces/sun-javaserver-faces-reference-implementation/configuring-jsf-20-to-run-on-the-google-appengine).

The project is just a basic JSF app with the web.xml from the linked article.

Is this a known problem? I'll also post it on the Google App Engine / Java forum.

```
 [java] INFO: Mojarra 2.0.6 (FCS FCS) für Kontext '' wird initialisiert.
 [java] 21.11.2011 16:10:50 com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
 [java] INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy-Annotationen vorhanden.  Verwaltete Bean-Methoden, die mit diesen Annotationen markiert sind, lassen die entsprechenden Annotationen verarbeiten.
 [java] 21.11.2011 16:10:50 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
 [java] SCHWERWIEGEND: Critical error during deployment: 
 [java] java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FaceletCache
 [java]         at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.createFaceletFactory(ApplicationAssociate.java:655)
 [java]         at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.<init>(ApplicationAssociate.java:227)
 [java]         at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.<init>(ApplicationImpl.java:210)
 [java]         at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationFactoryImpl.getApplication(ApplicationFactoryImpl.java:107)
 [java]         at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.getApplication(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:130)
 [java]         at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:256)
 [java]         at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
 [java]         at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:116)
 [java]         at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
 [java]         at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:216)
 [java]         at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:338)
 [java]         at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:226)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
 [java]         at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:186)
 [java]         at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:182)
 [java]         at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:172)
 [java]         at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:164)
 [java]         at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
 [java]         at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:113)
 [java]         at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:89)
 [java] 21.11.2011 16:10:50 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's supposed to be a field of the `WebConfiguration.WebContextInitParameter` enum which was introduced in Mojarra 2.0.3.

This particular exception suggests that you've both a Mojarra impl of version 2.0.2 or older **and** a Mojarra impl of version 2.0.3 or newer in your webapp's runtime classpath.

Cleanup it. Scan for duplicate `jsf-impl.jar` files and if necessary also the `javaee.jar` which actually originates from Glassfish.

Comment: The classpath includes a modified `WebConfiguration` class (required to remove JNDI class dependencies), which is now updated to a newer version supporting Mojarra 2.0.4 and it works now. The class name did not appear in the stack trace, many thanks for your help!